# When combining runes, can you get runes that you already have 9 of?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does rune combiner work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14604/how-does-rune-combiner-work)

When combining 5 runes to get a higher-tier one, can you get runes that you already have unlocked 9 of, or are you guaranteed to get a rune that you are still missing?

Comment: who is voting this duplicate? Is reading and comprehending that hard?

Comment: This is a duplicate because the first question is asking about how the rune combiner works. A *complete* answer to the first question should fully cover the nuances of the rune combiner and its mechanics, whose scope would cover this one. Feel free to ping the answerer (@Raven in this case) in a comment on the answer to get it updated, or alternatively, put a bounty on it so it gets more attention and you get the information you need.

Comment: @fae Maybe I just have a different understanding of what "exact" means. I am not asking how the rune combiner works... I am asking, very specifically, whether or not it respects the 9 rune limit. What is so hard to understand? I don't know how to phrase it differently.

Comment: @Hackworth This question's [currently under discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/what-should-we-do-about-dupes-that-dont-answer-the-question) here on our meta. Feel free to direct the question you have and any others about it there.

Answer (score -1):

As already covered in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14604/how-does-rune-combiner-work) the runes you get are random.

And since they are random you can get one you already own a full set(9) of.

Comment: if you always get the same rune from a certain combination, then surely there must be a recipe list somewhere?

Comment: @Ender thanks for pointing it out. My initial answer was only from my experience.

Comment: The question does not mention whether or not it can give you a 10th rune of a kind. I asked my question specifically because of that, since for example you can't buy more than 9 runes of a kind, so it's not unreasonable to think the rune combiner also respects that limit. So the answer you linked does not cover my question.

Comment: @Hackworth There would be no reason that I could have 15x +0.95 AD runes if not by this way.

Answer (score -2):

As already said, its random so you can get anything. You should probably try to combo first all lower tier runes, before buying all the runes you want.

Comment: I know it is random...That does not answer my question.

Comment: it does. you are just unable to read.